# Relatively prime $mx+ny = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

gcd$(x,y) = 1$

how can i prove that there exist $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}: mx+ny = 1$

I'm studying abstract algebra - cyclic group part, and wondering how $<d>$ is same group with $<r,s>$.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Bezout%27s_Lemma

Comment: The classical proof is obtained from the Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#Proof and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let be $A=\{mx+ny\in \Bbb N-\{0\} \, |\, m, n\in\Bbb Z\} $. Surely $A$ is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb N$, so it must have minimal element, call it $d$.
We want to prove that $d=\gcd (x, y) $, to this end let's write $d=mx+ny$.

On the one hand surely if $d'$ is a common divisor of $x$ and $y$ it must be a divisor of $mx+ny=d$.

On the other hand $d$ must be a common divisor of $x$ and $y$: infact we can write $x=ad+r$ with $0\le r<d$ but so $x=a(mx+ny) +r$ so $r\in A$ but $r<d$ that implies $r=0$ and so $d|x$. In the same way we can prove that $d|y$.

Now we have that $d$ is one common divisor of $x$ and $y$ and such that every other divisor divides it, so it must be $d=\gcd (x, y) $

Comment: I'm not sure why d is the biggest divisor. I guess i can only see d is common divisor.

Comment: @Jaehyun.Kim Every common divisor $\,d'\,$ is smaller than $\,d\,$ by $\,d'\mid d\Rightarrow d'\le d.\,$ The proof shows that any common divisor having such a  *linear* form is necessarily *greatest*.

Comment: Thanks for help